# How to install curl on python 3.x in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, curl, python-3.x

Can you please tell how to install curl for python 3.x to Windows 7. Ease_install only for the 2 version of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

There is no module called "curl", so it's unclear what you mean?

- PycURL?
- friendly_curl?
- pylibcurl?
- curlwrapper?
- pyparallelcurl?

In any case, as far as I can gather, none of them are ported to Python 3, so the answer on how to install them on Python 3 is: Talk to the authors and help port them! It's fun!